# Error Function name must be a string DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf

estoy tratando de generar un archivo PDF pero me esta dando el error: Function name must be a string

En mi controlador tengo esta funcion (le paso una variable desde la vista para que me traiga los datos de un user en especifico):

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

      public function fichaPDF($id){
            $tecnico = Tecnico::select('id','num_doc')
            ->where('id',$id)
            ->first();
            //return $tecnico;
            $data = $tecnico;
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('personal.tecnico.ficha', $data);
            return $pdf()->stream();
        }
```

El boton que tengo en la vista:

```
<a href="{{ route('tecnicos.ficha',$tecnico->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                <i class="fas fa-print fa-sm text-white-70"></i> Exportar Ficha Técnico PDF
</a>
```

La consulta funciona si quito el return $pdf()->stream(); (quitando esa linea y retornando la variable $tecnico veo la informacion)

Saludos

Comment: Se me hace confusa la consulta, en principio me parece que donde ponés return $pdf()->stream(); va return $pdf->stream(); o sea, sin los paréntesis en $pdf. Y adentro de stream('archivo.pdf') el nombre.

Comment: @FabianM toda la razon, tenia el () demas en $pdf... Gracias por el detalle